# On IronWorker, how can I remote build all the gems in a Gemfile?

Tags: ironworker, iron.io

Here is my Gemfile:

```
runtime 'ruby'
file 'Gemfile'
file 'config/database.yml', 'config/'                                                                                                                                         
file 'lib/models.rb', 'lib/'
remote_build_command 'bundle install --standalone'
exec 'my_worker.rb'
```

The remote_build_command, `bundle install --standalone` installs the gems, but they don't seem to load properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/builds/#remote_build), you can now specify a gemfile in your worker file. I don't think this was available when this question was asked.

```
# example.worker

runtime "ruby"

gemfile "Gemfile"

file "lib/model.rb", "lib"

full_remote_build true

# You can also add gems individually if you don't want to use a separate file.
gem "pg"
gem "aws-sdk"
```

Instead of having a remote_build_command, you specify `full_remote_build true`, or just `remote` to have IronWorker set up your environment for you.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install --standalone` installs the gems to `bundle/bundler/setup` directory. So at the top of `my_worker.rb`, add the following line:

```
require_relative 'bundle/bundler/setup'
```

This should load up all your gems.